# Android app install referral tracking in angular web-wrapped app?

Tags: android, angular, hybrid-mobile-app, angular-hybrid

I want to know, is it possible to track the install referral in angular web-wrapped android application? If it is possible then please let me know. I have searched a lot, but I have found nothing.